# canvas.toblob fails when a patterned fill is used

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, blob

I've been trying to find a method to save the canvas to file.   My image is too large to use dataToUrl, so I have been trying various toblob methods.   It seems that when a patterned fill is used, toblob does not work.   Would anyone be able to to me if it is possible for this to work or if there is another way to accomplish this?   Thanks

[jfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/GK4ph/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="canvas-to-blob.js"/></script>
<script src="FileSaver.js-master\FileSaver.js"></script>
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_lamp.jpg";
var pat = ctx.createPattern(img, "repeat");
ctx.rect(0, 0, 150, 100);

//Works with color, but not with pattern
ctx.fillStyle = pat;
//ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';

ctx.fill();

try {
    var isFileSaverSupported = !! new Blob();
} catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
alert("toBlob");
c.toBlob(function (blob) {
    alert("success");
    saveAs(blob, "TruVue.png");
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is due to [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), images from other domains are restricted - you can show them on the canvas but you cannot extract their bitmap.

As `toBlob` is a bitmap extracting method like `toDataURL` or `getImageData` you won't be able to use these images.

There are a couple of work-arounds:

- Upload the image to your own server and load it from there (same domain as you use for the page).
- Modify the other server to include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers (in this case it will probably not be do-able).
- Use your own server as an image proxy

BTW: You should also use the image's `onload` event to be sure the image gets proper loaded before using the image:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = drawFunction;
img.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_lamp.jpg";

function drawFunction() {
    /// draw here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am new to all of this, so I didn't CORS restrictions, I just thought w3schools would be an easy place to get an image.   The real images used are on the same domain.   I've only tested with everything on my local machine, but the results were the same.   I'll test it on the server now to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @DavidRay I forgot to mention that images loaded with `file://` protocol are also considered not from same origin, if this is what you use locally.

Comment: Same results on the server.

Comment: @ Ken  Tried again and it works, third refresh is the charm.   Thanks for your help!